# Google Identity Signin API always returns NULL with Server Client ID

Tags: android, authentication, oauth, google-signin

**[Addition]**

Based on my observations since having this issue: I feel like the issue is either dealing with...

- A bad Server Client ID
- Additional programming needed that is not provided out-of-the-box (i.e. an app engine module or server)

---

**[Original]**

I have successfully ran the sample at [Google Sign-In Android Sample App](https://github.com/googlesamples/google-services/tree/master/android/signin/app). 
My issue deals with the 2 Activities...ServerAuthCodeActivity and IdTokenActivity.

I went through the process of creating the `google-services.json` file and placed it in the correct spot. When I ran the app, I was able to successfully use 2 of the 4 provided Activities...

- Sign-in Activity: Basic Signing in
- Sign-in with Drive Activity: Basic Signing in plus Drive Authentication
- **ID Token Activity: Retrieves the ID Token form the logged in user**
- **Server Authentication Code Activity: Retrieve an Authentication code from an authenticated server.**

The first 2 examples work very well; **however, the last 2 activities just give me a** `null` **result.**

Before I could run the app, I noticed I needed to provide a `server_client_id` in `strings.xml`. I seen that the `google-services.json` had an OAuth client id that matched the requirements (ending in `apps.googleusercontent.com`), and placed that client id in the `strings.xml` file. Note: I tried to create an Android OAuth Client ID in the `Google Developer Console`, but it stated that I already had an OAuth Client ID for that project / package. So I figured the `google-services.json` file's client id was correct.

**So, is that the correct Server Client ID? Or am I suppose to get that ID from somewhere else?**

**Edit**

Here is my `google-services.json` file (condensed)

```
{

 "project_info": {
  ...
 },
 "client": [
   {
     "client_info": {
       ...
     },
     "oauth_client": [
       {
         "client_id": "*****.apps.googleusercontent.com", // HERE
         ...
       }
     ],
     ...
   }
 ],
 ...
}
```

Here is the result of the Authentication code after signing in
[image]

Comment: I noticed that `GoogleSignInResult result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);` leads to `result.isSuccess()` to be false. So it appears the authentication is failing....not that the authentication token was not available

Comment: I also tried to create a web application OAuth 2.0 credential that had its own Server-client-id and secret. However, that still seems to lead to a `result.isSuccess()` equal to `false`

Comment: Could you please help me with my issue, i spend some days trying to solve it... I use the same code, but finally when i retrive tokenId from google api, i get a String tokenId = <857 chars>... ?? If i tryed to validate it googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/tokeninfo?access_token= <857 chars response> i all the get 'error_description": "Invalid Value' ... How are you make a validation of your response? Are you also get String tokenId = <857 chars>?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know exactly why I ran into this problem; however, I did end up solving the issue.

**First, all samples provided by Google will all work without any additional code.** *(Edit: no addition web server code is needed; All that is needed is to provide the specific client id and such)* It is something I thought was true, but after running into this issue, I questioned that idea. I got in contact with an Android Developer Relations person, and they confirmed this fact.

Second, that person also gave me the following link, [Google Sign in for Android - Start](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/start). I told them that I DID follow that link, so I decided that there was some issue I had in the Developer Console that was causing this issue and that a creating a new Project was my best option.

### Solution

Based what I said, if you followed the link above and you are having this issue, then I would suggest just creating a **new project** and trying your luck again. This is just a sample project, so the amount of setup is small given the fact you already did it once.

Answer (score 3):

package name + signing cert SHA1 uniquely identifies an Android client. While package name is fixed in Google's sample, you will have to register it together with the signing cert you use (which can either come from your debug key store or a dedicated cert for testing)

Also, the web server needs to be registered in the same dev console project with a "Web" typed OAuth client and you have to paste the client id for that oAuth client into the sample code. - in this sense, you are right, Google in this case cannot provide a sample with zero additional code.

For others using the sample, **you will have to change strings.xml to put your client id for your "Web" typed OAuth client below**:

```
<string name="server_client_id">YOUR_SERVER_CLIENT_ID</string>
```

Just as a side note, the specified server_client_id will be the target audience in the id token or server auth code which you can pass to your server. Your server can then trust the token / code after appropriate validations. This is more secure than a bearer token. You can also take a look at this blogpost:
http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2016/01/using-google-sign-in-with-your-server.html

Comment: What is the use of google-services.json, if we still need to add "server_client_id" to the strings? Looks to me that it's used only for the reference and nothing else

Comment: @LukaBradeško , if Google Sign-In is the only Google API you are integrating, then you are right, the google-services.json is not necessary. See documentation here:https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/start-integrating#add-config. Some apps have multiple Web server OAuth2 clients for development / testing / production environments (i.e. multiple serverClientId in the same dev console project. So the API explicitly asks for the serverClientId)

Comment: And if you take a look at google-services.json, it only contains OAuth client info for your client applications, but not server applications at this moment.

Comment: Could you please help me with my issue, i spend some days trying to solve it... I use the same code, but finally when i retrive tokenId from google api, i get a String tokenId = <857 chars>... ?? If i tryed to validate it googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/tokeninfo?access_token= <857 chars response> i all the get 'error_description": "Invalid Value' ... How are you make a validation of your response? Are you also get String tokenId = <857 chars>?

Comment: @Aleksey, I assume you mean ID token (getIdToken()). If you use tokeninfo endpoint, please specify id_token=xxxx (instead of access_token=xxxx). Also, to quickly check content of an ID token, you can go to jwt.io as well.

Answer (score 3):

To get the server auth code, you need to request "offline access". Add requestServerAuthCode(), which seems to require your server's client_id (as opposed to any client_id valid for your project):

```
String serverClientId = getString(R.string.server_client_id);
GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
    .requestScopes(new Scope(/* whatever scope you're needing */))
    .requestServerAuthCode(serverClientId, false)
    .build();
```

See Google Sign-in for Android: [Enabling server-Side access](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/offline-access#before_you_begin)

Answer (score 0):

This could be a problem if the project you are developing on present android studio was actually first developed on some other android studio therefore SHA1 for the App doesn't match with your SHA1 so google couldn't verify this app therefore it returns null.You have to generate your OWN SHA1 and get you OWN client id then only google will return user data.